# Ring structure on K-theory modeled on fredholm operators

Tags: at.algebraic-topology

So, if we have an infinite dimensional Hilbert space $H$ then the way you put a ring structure on $F(H)$ is by taking the isomorphism $H\oplus H \to H$ we can define the sum of two Fredholm operators as 
$$ H \to H \oplus H \to H \oplus H \to H$$
where the middle map is the sum of the two operators.

What is the equivalent for the ring structure? I figured it's something to do with
$$ H \to H \otimes H \oplus H \otimes H \to H \otimes H \oplus H \otimes H \to H$$
but I cannot get the signs on the image map to work out. 
Also, is there a good reference to all this? Especially on how this works out when we switch to spectra.

Comment: I don't understand what the second map is supposed to be.

Comment: Have a look at Atiyah-Singer, ''Index theory for skew-adjoint Fredholm operators''. At the end of the paper, they discuss how to deal with the product structure.

Comment: I have no idea whether or not it is accessible, but I think this was studied in Marta Herrero's 1972 thesis at Chicago, ``Homology operations on H_*(BUxZ) and H_*(BOxZ) related to the tensor product of vector bundles''.  She was using Fredholm operators to model the tensor product.

Comment: @JohannesEbert I really like the simplicicty of the formula for a $\mathbb{Z}_2$ graded Hilbert space.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The formula is $$A \cdot B = \begin{bmatrix}
A \otimes I & -I \otimes B^* \\
I \otimes B &  A^* \otimes I 
\end{bmatrix}$$
the sign $- I \otimes B^*$ is to make associativity work out.

I found it in here: Klaus Janich. Vektorraumbundel und der Raum der Fredholm-Operatoren. Math. Ann., 161:129–142, 1965